# Catch when Console.CursorTop hits a location

Tags: c#, console

I'm writing a recursive method that searches for files and when it hits a match it prints the full path to the console window. Obviously, if this returns a lot of results it will quickly fill the screen not providing adequate time to review the results. I would like a method of catching when the console's `CursorLeft` property hits a certain position to insert `ReadKey()` to allow reviewing of the results. My search method is as follows

```
static void FileSearch(string Base, string Pattern)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Base)) return;

    string _Patt = Pattern.ToLower();

    var Files = Directory.GetFiles(Base).Where(File 
        => Path.GetFileName(File).ToLower().Contains(_Patt));

    foreach (string File in Files)
        Console.WriteLine(File);

    string[] Dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Base);

    foreach (string Dir in Dirs)
        FileSearch(Dir, Pattern);
}
```

I'm aware that I could add some sort of indexer, like an incrementing `int`, to keep track of the position and check it with each iteration of the loop, and that `int` could be passed as a `ref` so that all calls are looking at the same `int`. I'm also aware that with each iteration I could simply check the current position. I'm just wondering if there would be a cleaner way to accomplish this, perhaps something similar to event handling?

Comment: It sounds a little to me like you are over-engineering this. Why not just give a /p (for page) option and stop for every Console.WindowHeight lines and prompt. Or else just output the whole thing and let the user pipe to "more" if she needs to?

Comment: A static `int` wouldn't suffice? It would be trivial to implement..

Comment: This is actually a stripped down version of what I'm doing. This is implemented as part of a class library to provide more advanced search functionality, such as searches using regular expressions. My goal is to eliminate the need for checking a position within the recursive method to keep the search method itself as short as possible. I'm beginning to agree however that I'm over analyzing this and giving myself more of a headache than some stylistic improvements are worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Console.CursorTop` is the right property to look at. Check for the following after printing each line:

```
if (Console.CursorTop % (Console.WindowHeight - 1) == 0)
    Console.ReadKey();
```

as in:

```
static void FileSearch(string Base, string Pattern)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Base)) return;

    string _Patt = Pattern.ToLower();

    var Files = Directory.GetFiles(Base).Where(File 
        => Path.GetFileName(File).ToLower().Contains(_Patt));

    foreach (string File in Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(File);
        if (Console.CursorTop % (Console.WindowHeight - 1) == 0)
            Console.ReadKey();
    }

    string[] Dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Base);

    foreach (string Dir in Dirs)
        FileSearch(Dir, Pattern);
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to avoid but it's been pointed out to me that I may be making this harder than it's worth, and your answer is actually checking it in a way that I hadn't previously thought of, so at this point I see this as the best answer.